# google map with multiple markers is not appearing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, razor

I want to display multiple markers on google map.I am using for each loop to iterate over the model list that contains latitude and longitude.But function is called and it does not show a map.

code:

```
      <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 80%; height: 80%">  </div>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
     </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
       sensor=false"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("working");
    var map;
    var locations = [];

    var options = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0], options);


    @* This is the razor loop *@
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <text>
    locations.push(item.latitude, item.longitude);

    </text>
     }
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i <= locations.length; i++) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
        });

    }

});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will not work:

```
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markerlatLng);
```

`markerlatLng` already is a `google.maps.LatLng`, the result will be an invalid LatLng.

Use `markerlatLng` as `center`-property for `options`

Furthermore: you should separate the map-creation from the loop. Create the map before the loop amd set the center after the loop:

```
map.setCenter(markerlatLng);
```

Additionally:
the map-property of the markers has to be `map` not `map_canvas`